# Filterable and sortable at the same time React Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

Hopefully you can help me with a problem that i have.
I'm using React Table on my site.
I'd like to use the properties filterable and sortable at the same time. I've noticed that when I use filterable, sortable doesn't work anymore. Can be a bug of React Table? Do you know how can I tackle this problem?

```
const columns = () => [
{
  Header: 'Name',
  accessor: 'name',
  sortable: true,
},
{
  Header: 'ID',
  accessor: 'id',
  width: 80,
  sortable: true,
},
{
  Header: 'Country',
  accessor: 'country',
  width: 100,
  filterable: true,
  Filter: ({ filter, onChange }) => (
    // DROPDOWN WITH OPTIONS ...
  ),
},
```

]

Comment: Provide other parts of your code that deal with creating the table and rendering. This code is not enough to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can make a table filterable and sortable at the same time with react-table hooks. I created an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/filterable-and-sortable-react-table-7ed94) to illustrate it:

You don't need to pass `sortable` or `filterable` props to your array of columns. If you implemented filtering on your table and want to add sorting all you have to do is to follow next steps:

1. Import `useSortBy` hook
2. Call it inside `useTable` hook after `useFilters` hook : `useTable(..., useFilters, useSortBy)`
3. Add to your `th` element some UI which will show a user the order of sorting:

```
<span>
{column.isSorted ? 
  column.isSortedDesc
  ? " "
  : " "
  : ""}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that i was using react-table v6. As some of you have said, definitely was possible to use filterable and sortable at the same time. Unfortunately it seems that this need to be done using a different row. If for example you want to filter by a dropdown, this is place underneath the column label.

After debugging a lot, I noticed that my problem came from CSS. The filterable row was on the top of the columns label and therefore, disabling the sortable function. Not sure if you have ever seen an example of how to tackle this. To replace the column label for the the select tag. If so.. i'll really appreciate if you share it.
Thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score -1):

This is a modification that shows how it can work for you (as your entire solution was not shared).
See: https://github.com/vaclav18/react-table/blob/master/examples/filtering/src/App.js

Live example is here:
https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/filtering

The live example is for filtering only - so the changes would be at:
line 3
line 277
line 347 The sortable: true is not necessary here

Please refer to /docs/src/pages/docs/api/useSortBy.md for more insight.